# Get SagePay CardType value from a Woocommerce order

Tags: woocommerce, opayo

I'm using Sagepay payment gateway with woocommerce.  When an order is processed, Sagepay returns the CardType value and it is visible in the Order Note that is created.  I need to get this value.

I was hoping I could get it using wc_get_order but I can't find it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

It is in the _sageresult field in the wp_postmeta table.

```
$notes=get_post_meta($order_id,'_sageresult',true);

echo $notes['CardType'];
```